# How to subscribe from Angular to a NestJs Observable?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, observable, subscribe, nestjs

I'm doing an application in angular 7 with database in Firestore, but to avoid the cloud functions, I decided to backend with NestJs (5), and I use the firebase-admin transactions to keep the embedded data synchronized. Everything seems to work well when I do the consultations, my nestjs backend is responsible for collecting and joining them to respond to my frontend application in angular. But here my real question: What do I have to do to make my back end in nestjs return an observable to the angular frontend?

What I want to achieve is that my fronted detect the changes in real time of firestore through my backend in NestJs.

Introduction I'm doing an application in angular 7 with database in Firestore, but to avoid the cloud functions, I decided to backend with NestJs (5), and I use the firebase-admin transactions to keep the embedded data synchronized. Everything seems to work well when I do the consultations, my nestjs backend is responsible for collecting and joining them to respond to my frontend application in angular. But here my real question: What do I have to do to make my back end in nestjs return an observable to the angular frontend?

What I want to achieve is that my fronted detect the changes in real time of firestore through my backend in NestJs.

I understand that from NestJs we can return as a result of an observable so that from angular you subscribe to the changes in real time.

Firestore -> Nestjs (runing in Firebase functions) -> Angular (.subscribe)

Current function in NestJs:

```
async getAllAdministratorsForFirestore(): Promise<Administrator[]> {

    const administratorsSnapshot = await administratorsRef.get();
    const administrators = [];
    administratorsSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      administrators.push(mapFirestoreDocs(doc.id, doc.data()));
    });

    return administrators;
  }
```

Current consumer in Angular:

```
subscribeToAdministratorsForNestJs() {

    this.http.get(nestJsEndPointUrl, options).subscribe((administrators) => {
      this.administrators = administrators;
    })
  }
```

What I want to achieve is that my fronted detect the changes in real time of firestore through my backend in NestJs.

**But how do I do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want to do, you need the `@nestjs/websockets` package that is included in NestJs and the `ngx-socket-io` package in Angular.

With that, you can subscribe to the changes that your firestore database emits when someone connects to the `@WebSocketServer () server` that generates NestJs and sends them through the method

```
client.broadcast.emit ('change', changes);
```

and from angular only you subscribe to the event change:

```
this.socket.fromEvent ('change'). subscribe ((changes) => console.log (changes));
```

And that's it;), a suggestion when the users connected to that socket is 0, unsubscribe to the changes in the firestore database.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ing Alejandro Villalón, your response has marked the way to take, because I really had no idea how to do it.
It was these concepts that I needed.